# How to fix "TypeError : only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Tags: python, plot, error-handling, bar-chart, typeerror

This is my code.

```
%pylab inline
import numpy as np
y = np.array(([75], [82], [93]), dtype=float)
bar([0,1,2], y, width = 0.35, alpha=0.8)
```

I got this error.

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

If I don't want to edit this line

```
y = np.array(([75], [82], [93]), dtype=float)
```

Could you tell me how to convert y to size-1 arrays before using this command?

```
bar([0,1,2], y, width = 0.35, alpha=0.8)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options

```py
y.flatten()
y.ravel()
y.reshape(-1)
```